# Autofill Behavior

Tags: civicontribute

To be clear, when I say "autofill" I'm referring to the browser remembering previously entered data and subsequently offering them as a drop-down option list.

CiviCRM's behavior in this regard seems inconsistent when entering contributions in Chrome:

Method 1: When entering a new contribution via the contributions menu, the "Source" entries are remembered. No problem here.

Method 2: When entering a new contribution via the Contributions tab on a person's record, the "Source" entries are not remembered. However, past entries using method 1 are displayed as autofill options.

The behavior happens for some Chrome users, but not others with seemingly-identical settings, systems, and versions. Toggling and/or clearing autofill collection does not resolve it. Using Firefox does resolve the issue, but is not a viable option for some in my organization.

Does anyone know how to make Chrome remember entries when using Method 2, above? Thanks for humoring me. Chrome forums have not been helpful so far.